# How can I perform sequential stage/jobs/task/steps on ONE container [reuse it] in Azure Devops?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-devops

The following structure ensures that each `Stage` does run sequentially. However each stage *builds a new container*.  I need the sequential actions to work on *one* container.

```
      - stage: build
        jobs:
        - job: build_main
          pool:
            type: linux  # read more about custom job pool types at https://aka.ms/obpipelines/yaml/jobs
          variables:
            ob_outputDirectory: '$(REPOROOT)\out'
            ob_sdl_binskim_break: true
          steps:
            - task: Bash@3
              displayName: "Install conda/python3.10, unixodbc, pytest and requirements"
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                workingDirectory: $(FRAMEWORK_DIR)
                script: |
                    make setup-python-in-ubuntu
                    make setup-local

      - stage: test
        dependsOn: build
        jobs:
        - job: test_main
          pool:
            type: linux  # read more about custom job pool types at https://aka.ms/obpipelines/yaml/jobs
          variables:
            ob_outputDirectory: '$(REPOROOT)\out'
            ob_sdl_binskim_break: true
          steps:
            - task: Bash@3
              displayName: "Run tests"
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                workingDirectory: $(FRAMEWORK_DIR)
                script: |
                    make test
            - task: Bash@3
              displayName: "Run unit tests report"
              inputs:
                filePath: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/framework/scripts/run-unit-tests-report
```

It is acceptable to use *any* combination of `stage`/`job`/`task`/`step` as long as those two requirements are met:

- Sequential
- Operate on the *same* container

How can this be done in `ADO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Sequential; Operate on the same container* - this is only for the tasks level. Each job is a separate build instance with its own checkout steps and build environment: [jobs.job definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines)

> A job is a collection of steps run by an agent or on a server.